# jQuery fadeTo to a different color

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout, fadeto

I am trying to fadeTo a different color other than the white it fades to with the following code:

```
$(titleName).fadeTo("slow", 0.3, function () {
    $(titleName).attr('data-marked', 'yes');
});
```

How can I fade it to another color other than white using the code above?

Comment: fadeTo animates the opacity, the reason it's white is because the element behind it is white. To animate colors you need a plugin or jQuery UI.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery can't animate colors, just numbers. jQuery UI can.

If you don't want to include jQuery UI, you can use the "step" callback of animate().
For example:

```
var div, intVal, color;
div = $(".title")

div .css({
        myAttr: 0
    })
    .animate({
        myAttr: 255
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        step: function (currentVal) {
            intVal = Math.round(currentVal);
            color = "rgb(" + intVal + ",0, 0)";
            div.css("background-color", color);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(titleName).animate({
    opacity: 0.3,
    color: 'red'
}, "slow", function () {
    $(this).attr('data-marked', 'yes');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EcW86/) or [Background](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EcW86/3/)

Note: You need to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com)/[jQuery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to enable animation of color like font color/background color

Comment: Still is white as it fades

Answer (score 0):

Use the JQuery color animation plugin:
http://jqueryui.com/animate/